# Custom Reports for Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Am trying to Load the Data from Mysql to an Xml file which is created using QTRPT.
Here i made a report tempate such that i can load data into it . but my end user need custom report concept i.e he can select the fields From Data base . For this i need to create the fields of QTRPT at runtime and load the data accordingly so for making this to happen is there any provision for that and if the user selects more fields also we need to manage the page size and make it look either landscape or portrait mode .
Note: All these reports should be printable to A4 sheet .
Is there a way such that i can full fill this custom report concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the beams symmetrical and horizontally placed (eg. their x should never overlap by less than a diameter ) then you could simply compute the centroid of the image (cx,cy), then compute the centroids for the subimages `x<cx` and `x>cx`, resulting in the centroids of the corresponding beams.

If you know that the left(right) beam is always placed farther than a radius from the image center, you can skip the first pass and just compute the centroids of each halve directly.

If the beam are abitrarily placed but not overlapping, you can compute the variance matrix and split the view based on the largest eigenvalue.

If they can overlap/have noise, you'll need a clustering algorithm or develop some kind of robust statistics dependending on some beam statistical model.

If they cannot overlap, there's no noise, there's a known max diameter, etc... and the image shown are actually 01-valued, the thing can be made much faster, of course.